# Login with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, login-script

I'm using c# to make login form with linq to sql

```
{
        linqclassDataContext context = new linqclassDataContext();
        var q = from p in context.Tables
                where p.username == txtUsername.Text
                && p.password == txtPassword.Text
                select p;



        if (q.Any())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

when I compile and try to login the exception comes out to--> if (q.Any()) this line
  any ideas of it?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Side note - may I assume that you encrypt passwords? Other side note: `return q.Any();` is enough. Show the error please.

Comment: @GertArnold I don't think you can assume that since he's pulling the value directly out of a `TextBox` it seems.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

Additional information: SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types.

Comment: Well, I guess you have to check your database data types in `Tables` (is that the real name, by the way???).

Comment: my password type is text coz I was encrypting them but then I've just putted in string after this excepption

Comment: You don't need Text to store encrypted data. Well, at least you know why you get this error.

Comment: `text` means `varchar(max)`. Do you really expect passwords that are longer than 8K? And why should one have to use only Latin characters for the password? Please *don't* try to roll your own authentication mechanism.